# How would I go about making text like this?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I am designing a poster for fun and I found this text somewhere online. I wanted to attempt to recreate it but I am completely stumped. I am really new to Illustrator so any answer with as much depth and detail as possible would be really appreciated.

[image: text design to re-create]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn some basics. You'll find surely 1000 video tutorials and guidance writings of the following Illustrator topics:

- fills
- strokes
- groups
- Appearance panel
- drawing with the pen
- writing text objects
- converting texts to outlines
- clipping masks
- 3D effect Rotate
- 3D effect Bevel & Extrude
- Expanding the appearance and editing manually the result of 3D effects

Shortly: You can write a text, outline it and draw the decorative line pattern. Use the text as a clipping mask for the decorative pattern. Group the result with the colored text.

Then with 3D Rotate add perspective to the decorated text. Write the dialog numbers onto paper

Fix the effect by expanding the appearance, draw manually the 3D thickness shape or generate it from a copy of the original writing with 3D effect Bevel & Extrude. You need the written numbers. Expand and place.

After fighting through this you surely know something.